# How to send array to register.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm using default auth in laravel and want to send array with some data from some table to register.blade.php. I've just tried this one (method from RegisterController):

```
public function checkgroup(){
            $group=Group::all();
            return view('auth.register', compact ('group'));
        }
```

But it still return "undefined variable group". I've tried with another controllers and views-works good.
Anв here is a part of register.blade.php

```
<select name="checkgroup">
                                @foreach($group as $groups)
<option value="{{$groups->id}}">{{$groups->name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
</select>
```

RegisterController

```
use RegistersUsers;


protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}


protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}


protected function create(array $data, Request $request)
{
    $user=User::create([
        /*dd($request->role),*/
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'patro' => $data['patro'],
        'surname' => $data['surname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
          
    $user->assignRole($request->input('role'));


   
        }
        public function checkgroup(){
            $group=Group::all();
            return view('auth.register', compact ('group'));
        }
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all(), $request)));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    if ($response = $this->registered($request, $user)) {
        return $response;
    }

    return $request->wantsJson()
        ? new JsonResponse([], 201)
        : redirect($this->redirectPath());
}}
```

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code, so you must be making a mistake somewhere else. Do other controller methods use this view?

Comment: @Donkarnash 8.16.1

Comment: @miken32 i've added RegisterController code to post

Comment: Have you tried using View composer?

Comment: Make sure you clear all view caches? What does the route definition look like and what URL are you visiting when you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using `laravel/ui` package for auth related scaffolding. As per this the `showRegistrationForm` method handles the `/register` route to show the registration form.

You can check which Controller and method is responsible for handling the route by running `php artisan route:list` in the terminal.

The controller method to show the registration form is within the RegistersUsers trait.

You need to override that method to pass additional data to the register view.

Have this method in your RegisterController

```php
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    $groups = Group::all();
    return view('auth.register', compact('groups');
}
```

Then in your `auth/register.blade.php` include the snippet for the groups

```
<select name="checkgroup">
    @foreach($groups as $group)
        <option value="{{$group->id}}">{{$group->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: yeah, it works, thnx. but when i try php artisan route:list it returns   Target class [Auth\RegisterController] does not exist.

Comment: okay, problem with route:list is solved. thnx

Comment: @ichwillkin If the answer solved the issue in your question pls remember to mark as accepted/upvote for the benefit of the subsequent visitors